# Processmaker 3 and Redis

Tags: php, session, redis, processmaker

I am trying to implement failover and load balance in our Processmaker 3.5 community edition installation. For that i need to integrate a single source of authentication. To do that we have identified Redis as a single source of session manager. But due to lack of any information online, i am unable to start on this.

Any reference or help is appreciated.

Due to lack of resources online, havent got to start yet.